# stuck in js scripting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got a problem in using mouseover.
I am working on html,php and js.
Actually I am making a page in which i want to change the source of my image.
But the problem is I am fetching my values from database then calling a function to change src with the fetched data.
But its not working at all. Please tell me the error if you can encounter it.
I am using thumbnails in it.

Heres my html code

```
<form id='purchase' name='info' action='index.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='imagelink' value='".$row1['images']."'/>
</form>

    <img name='unique' src='".$row1['images']."1.jpg'/>

<a href='#' id='1'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/1.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' id='2'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/2.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' id='3'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/3.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' id='4'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/4.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' id='5'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/5.jpg' /></a>
```

Heres js file :

```
window.onload = function() {
                var image = document.info.imagelink;
                document.getElementById('1').onmouseover = function() {
                        document.unique.src=image+'1.jpg';
                        return false;
                };
                document.getElementById('2').onmouseover = function() {
                        document.unique.src=image+'2.jpg';
                        return false;
                };
                document.getElementById('3').onmouseover = function() {
                        document.unique.src=image+'3.jpg';
                        return false;
                };
                document.getElementById('4').onmouseover = function() {
                        document.unique.src=image+'4.jpg';
                        return false;
                };
                document.getElementById('5').onmouseover = function() {
                        document.unique.src=image+'5.jpg';
                        return false;
                };
        };
```

$row1['images'] is partial path of my images which is saved in my database.

Comment: Post rendered HTML, PHP is not needed here.

Comment: Have you verified the paths to the images work? Some browsers will show you a broken image icon, others hide the image and don't show you anything. (It drives me nuts) An easy thing to do is try pasting one of your generated URLs for the images into your address bar and verify you've got the path right. If you're off by one character, it'll break. (I've done this and missed things like slashes before)

Answer (score 2):

in your `window.onload` function, the line:

```
var image = document.info.imagelink;
```

will not give the imagelink value, you need to get the value by changing the line into:

```
var image = document.info.imagelink.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use jQuery? You could achieve the effect with something like this:

```
$(".thmb").click(function() {
    $("#unique").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

In your HTML, put it like this:

```
<img name='unique' id="unique" src='".$row1['images']."1.jpg'/>

<a href='#' class='thmb' id='1'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/1.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' class='thmb' id='2'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/2.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' class='thmb' id='3'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/3.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' class='thmb' id='4'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/4.jpg' /></a>
<a href='#' class='thmb' id='5'><img src='".$row1['images']."thumbs/5.jpg' /></a>
```